# vb.net subtraction giving error message for subtracting two numbers

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to use this code in vb.net

```
num_days = todate_split(0) - fromdate_split(0)
```

to find out the number of days between. for example, todate_split(0) equals 20 and fromdate_split(0) equals 5 so it should return 15

but i get an error saying:

```
Operator '-' is not defined for types 'Char' and 'Char'
```

UPDATE:

I am using this code too:

```
fromdate_split.Split("/")
```

to split the strings

they are in date format, so for example 30/12/2015

and i want to get the difference between the two dates (days)

Comment: What is `todate_split` and `fromdate_split`?

Comment: if `todate_split` and the other are string, the (0) references one character in the string.  Char types cant be used with subtraction because it is nonsense. If they are arrays, strings too cant be subtracted. Turn on Option Strict.

Comment: Well the error speak for himself. You are tryng to use a "-" operator between char values. The problem is with your functions todate_split and fromdate_split

Comment: If you are trying to get the number of days difference between 2 dates, use a proper `DateTime` type.  They subtract just fine.

Comment: what to i need to define those two variables as? They were being defined as String

Comment: You possibly want something like this: `num_days = CInt(todate_split) - CInt(fromdate_split)`

Comment: `fromdate_split.Split("/")` this is also wrong as is, you need to assign the result to something or you **are** referencing the chars in the original string, not the split

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is parse the *dates* and get a [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.days(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb):

```
Dim todate As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(todateString)
Dim fromdate As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(fromdateString)

Dim diff As TimeSpan = todate - fromdate
```

This way you get the number of days with:

```
Dim days As Int32 = diff.Days
```

Comment: I was writing this but you hit submit first. May the faster fingers win!

Comment: The OP may not need to even parse it - it may have been a Date type to start with that was converted to string for the purpose of doing the math

Comment: @Plutonix: OP indicates that they are strings: "to split the strings". But in essence you're correct.

Answer (score 2):

If `todate_split` and `fromdate_split` are strings which seems to be the case given the error message you can't subtract them. I suspect that you have `Option Strict` to `Off` and that the strings are `"20"` and `"5"`.

Instead either use `Int32` in the first place or use `Int32.Parse(string)` to parse them:

```
Dim todate As Int32 = Int32.Parse(todate_split)
Dim fromdate As Int32 = Int32.Parse(fromdate_split)
```

But i strongly recommend to set `Option Strict` to `On` as default in visual studio and to use the correct types. You will learn a lot  and you'll write safer and more efficient code.

---

Since you've now mentioned that you want to know the difference in days between two dates which are represented as string in the format `30/12/2015`. Use `Date.Parse` to parse them to `DateTime` and then subtract them to get a `TimeSpan` which has a `Days` property.

Something like:

```
Dim fromdate As Date = Date.Parse("15/12/2015")
Dim todate As Date = Date.Parse("30/12/2015")
Dim timespan As TimeSpan = todate - fromdate
Dim days As Int32 = timespan.Days
```

If you don't know if the format is valid use `Date.TryParse`.

Comment: @CharlesF: i have already edited my answer. Use `Date.Parse` and subtract them, then use `timeSpan.Days`.

Answer (score 0):

The DateTime class can do everything for you:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Globalization

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim fromDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("28/07/2015", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        Dim toDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("30/12/2015", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

        Dim timeSpan As TimeSpan = toDate.Subtract(fromDate)
        Console.WriteLine(timeSpan.Days)

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Results:

[image]

Reference:

The DateTime.ParseExact performs the split for you
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx